# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..2: 3 i cant fix

Tags: flutter

i have a problem this my list

```
             class _FitnessAppState extends State<FitnessApp> {
```

String img_Header =
"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517836357463-d25dfeac3438?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80";
List trainingImage = [
"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534258936925-c58bed479fcb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1631&q=80",
"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1575052814086-f385e2e2ad1b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80",
"https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/picture-of-people-running-on-treadmill-in-gym-picture-id879180126?k=20&m=879180126&s=612x612&w=0&h=WZ1Iqcqv5_rNTNslUscoMg9qAUoNiDG8kWBfVnpPapQ=",
];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your variables are:

```
String img_Header = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517836357463-d25dfeac3438?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80";

List trainingImage = [
"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534258936925-c58bed479fcb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1631&q=80",
"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1575052814086-f385e2e2ad1b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80",
"https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/picture-of-people-running-on-treadmill-in-gym-picture-id879180126?k=20&m=879180126&s=612x612&w=0&h=WZ1Iqcqv5_rNTNslUscoMg9qAUoNiDG8kWBfVnpPapQ=",
];
```

the error of RangeError is happened in `trainingImage` variable as it is a List datatype, that's because you are trying to access an unavailable index inside a List, as example, your list `trainingImage` has only 3 elements  which start by index 0 and ends by index 2:

```
print(trainingImage[0]);
// output: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534258936925-c58bed479fcb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1631&q=80"

print(trainingImage[1]);
// output: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1575052814086-f385e2e2ad1b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80"

print(trainingImage[2]);
// output: "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/picture-of-people-running-on-treadmill-in-gym-picture-id879180126?k=20&m=879180126&s=612x612&w=0&h=WZ1Iqcqv5_rNTNslUscoMg9qAUoNiDG8kWBfVnpPapQ="
```

if you are trying to access the index 3 you will get the error of RangeError:

```
print(trainingImage[3]);
// output: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..2: 3
```

the solution is to always check if an index is available before accessing it:

```
// as example you want to access the index 3
int index = 3;

// 1st way
if(trainingImage.asMap().containsKey(index))
{
// run this if index 3 is available
}

// 2nd way
if(index < trainingImage.length && index >= 0)
{
// run this if index 3 is available
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet that you have provided is fine. Maybe you are accessing wrong index of the list. Can you provide more information please?

However, I'll suggest you to rename the `img_Header` variable to `imgHeader` otherwise it will show **lowerCamelCase** warning.

Comment: i made it but its doesnt work

Comment: SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                  ),
                  listItem(trainingImage[0], "Full Body", 53, 30),
                  listItem(trainingImage[1], "Yoga Training", 30, 10),
                  listItem(trainingImage[2], "Kardio Training", 60, 10),
                  listItem(trainingImage[3], "Full Body Program", 53, 30),
                ],
              ),

Comment: do you use discord can i share my screen and you can help me please

Comment: But you do not have a trainingImage[3] item in the list. trainingImage.length is 3. trainingImage[0], trainingImage[1] & trainingImage[2] are only valid items. To access trainingImage[3] first you need to add a new url inside your list.